# CSS Rendering inconsistency on ul with Firefox being the odd ball out

Tags: html, css, debugging

### Background

I was creating a secondary navigation menu using embedded unordered lists with anchors and headers. Using a CSS reset sheet all headers and anchors are set to "display: block". When list-style-position: inside is set Firefox and Camino render the headers and anchors below the bullet while Safari, Camino, and IE render it inline.

### Example Screen Shots

[image: Firefox and Camino rendering]
<sub>(source: [michaelgrace.org](https://geek.michaelgrace.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/firefox.png))</sub>
[image: Safari, Opera, and IE rendering]
<sub>(source: [michaelgrace.org](https://geek.michaelgrace.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/safari.png))</sub>

### Example Code

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* css reset */
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a { display: block; }

    /* list styling */
    ul { list-style-position: inside; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Primary</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h4>Secondary</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>Tertiary</h5>
            <ul>        
              <li><a href="#">Tertiary Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>
</body>
</html>
```

To get Firefox and Camino to render the same as the others I set the unordered lists, headers, and links to "display: inline" but I still want to know...

### Question

**Why does Firefox & Camino render the list item below the list bullet when Safari, Opera, & IE render it "normal"?**

Comment: Your example code has no Doctype so triggers Quirks mode. I find that Quirks mode is too much pain to deal with so I wouldn't event try to wonder why a certain behaviour was happening while it was active.

Comment: @David 
Thank you for your comment. I have tried several different Doctypes and it has not made a difference in any of the browsers I tested in. I was originally working on an xhmtl 1.0 transitional document when I ran into the problem.

Comment: Use firebug. It will give you some clues.

Comment: @Antony Firebug Rocks! But, unfortunately it hasn't been very helpful in this case. If there is a way to view the padding and dimensions on bullets for list items, it would be more useful but as of currently I don't know how to do that in Firebug.

Answer (score 30):

### Update

This is actually broken and has been since 2000. Still not fixed. I thought I had figured it out but it was a mistake on my part. STILL BROKEN! :(

### Answer

Setting the CSS property of "list-style" to "disc" will cause the Firefox and Camino rendering engine, Gecko, to render the headers inside an unordered list "normal".

### Answer Background

After following @o.k.w's advice of digging into the rendering engine I found that my problem had been reported on bugzilla.mozilla.org on April 22, 2000! (*Cough* Um, Mozilla... the bug is still there.) The reported bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36854 discusses the fact that Mozilla's rendering engine, [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29), has a problem displaying headers in an unordered list while displaying the list item marker inside. It also says about this problem:

> "This actually seems to be a major CSS1 compliance issue..." - David Baron

At the bottom of the bug report thread there is a link a w3c.org document that led me to find my fix:

> "There is a description in a CSS 2.0 recommendation:
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#q11 which tell us that Gecko behavior
>   is faulty."  - Listy Blaut

At the bottom of that document there is a suggestion to set the CSS list-style to disc:

```
ul        { list-style: disc }
```

Setting the unordered list list-style to "disc" has "fixed" the rendering problem in Gecko rendering engine browsers, Firefox & Camino, while leaving the lists unchanged in other browsers. *Note: Although "disc" is a [list-style-type property](http://w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_style_liststyle.asp), if "list-style-type: disc" is used instead of "list-style: disc" it does not fix the problem.

### Solution Example Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* css reset */
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a { display: block; }

        /* list styling */
        ul { list-style-position: inside; list-style: disc;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Primary</h3>
          <ul>
             <li>
                <h4>Secondary</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                     <h5>Tertiary</h5>
                     <ul>            
                        <li><a href="#">Tertiary Link</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     <ul>
</body>
</html>
```

### How I feel finding the answer to my own question

[image]
<sub>(source: [michaelgrace.org](https://geek.michaelgrace.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/answered_my_own_question.jpg))</sub>

I can finally sleep ; )

Comment: Upvoted for the pure awesome of photographic evidence. Dude; that's just made me the most entertained person in this hemisphere =)

Comment: @Mike Farmer, Thanks, I will.

Comment: @drthomas, Thank you. Words just weren't enough to describe my excitement so I had to use a picture. ; ) Thanks for the vote.

Comment: @Mike That was a good one! Both the answer and the photo :) Glad I help in some way.

Comment: @o.k.w, Thank you and thank you for your help. See you around the stack.  ;)

@Justin Jodnson, Thanks.

Comment: So, after some more review of my own answer it looks like I was right about the rendering engine having a bug about the rendering. Setting the UL list-style to disc however doesn't actually fix the problem, it just makes it look like it does. Doesn't look like there is a fix for this problem at this time except to use a different html layout to accomplish a similar effect. ; D

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer to make it clearer there is no fix and that this has been broken in Firefox since 2000?

Comment: Used to solve a display gap between Chrome & Firefox on `<li>`'s with `list-style-position: inside;` Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Because a heading is a block element and therefore gets pushed to the next line (since a block-level element *displaying* as `block` (or without an otherwise specified `display`-type [`inline-block`, `inline`, etc...] gets) can't share a line; I don't know if a list-element should (or shouldn't), according to spec, contain block level elements *inside* itself, or if it should be presumed to be 'sharing' the line with the contained element.

I could be wrong, about all of this, though; it's just the only explanation I could think of.

You may, also, find that there are default margins, padding or positioning being applied to the heading elements in Firefox. You could test with Firebug (or alternatives) to see where the positioning is coming from.

---

## edit

After copy-pasting your code into my template file, and viewing in FF3.0.10 I don't see the problem you report. The resulting code I used is pasted below, if you haven't already resolved this, try the code, below, and see if the problem persists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    /* css reset */
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a { display: block; }

    /* list styling */
    ul {  width: 14em; margin: 1em auto;}
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Primary</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h4>Secondary</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>Tertiary</h5>
            <ul>        
              <li><a href="#">Tertiary Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to copy and paste the code and test it in FF 3.0.10. I re downloaded FF 3.0.11 to test the code after I saw that you were using 3.0.x. I ran my code in FF 3.0 and found that it is still giving me the same problem. The code that you have pasted back into your answer is missing the CSS styling of  "list-style-position: inside". Thank you again for taking the time to test this but it looks like I will still be in search of an answer to why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

I tried both samples and experimented a bit myself.

The differentiating factor is strangely "list-style-position". Somehow in FF, "inside" and "outside" have "inline" and "block" effects for the bullets.

I can't tell you why, probably need to dig into the rendering engine.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to dig in and try this out for yourself. I will see if I can find some information on the rendering engine that Firefox and Camino use since they are both Mozilla products. +1 vote for your efforts. ; )

Comment: @o.k.w I found the answer and fixed my own problem! I am soo excited. I am writing the answer now and will post it soon. ; ) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Mike Great! Looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 2):

`list-style: disc` is interpreted as `list-style: disc outside` so I think that just avoids FF's layout problem instead of fixing it.

I'm having some success with a workaround that sets the first-child of the list-item to `display: inline`, which puts the marker back in the right place:

http://jsfiddle.net/6GhPT/2/

I've seen the same incorrect rendering (list markers displayed above block children of list items) in IE ≤ 9, too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've had same problem, but circle was not an option - I needed the decimal notation. After few minutes of research, I've found a perfect solution with

`ol {
        counter-reset: li;
    }
    ol li h4:before {
        content: counter(li) ". ";
        counter-increment: li;
    }`

On the element I want to append the list-style item (In my case it was ol>li>div>h3! It can be positioned relative/absolute also). Effect is great, number of item is perfectly concatenated with H3 content.

I really suggest you to try this. Here is full tutorial: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/

Answer (score 0):

hotfix:

```
.dpe-flexible-posts li::before{
    content: '●';
    position: absolute;
    left: -14px;
    top: -1px;
}
.dpe-flexible-posts li{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to have to give this a try. Thanks!