# bullets not centered vertically in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, list, vertical-alignment

In Chrome and Safari I've found that li bullet discs sit 1px below being vertically centered (yes its only 1px but that pixel matters to my design team). Is there anyway to correct this without altering the html, replacing the bullets with images or creating them with psuedo elements?

note: since the text is 9px high and the bullet is 4 it will always end up either 1px too high or low, my issue is that its an additional pixel below that.

[image: image example]

```
ul {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/VWnXr/

Comment: The problem in part is due to how the bullets are drawn in the various browsers.  The bullet motif in Firefox is larger than that in Chrome, and the placement may also depend on the default font selection on the end user's machine.

Comment: Man I love driving up development budgets solving x-browser issues that don't matter to anybody except some maniacal designer.

Comment: agree with @RyanWheale !!

Comment: Ah thank you for confirming my thoughts @Marc-Audet, I figured that was the case but thought I'd throw it out to the masses in case there was some trick I wasn't aware of before having to go back to the designers with my tail between my legs. RIGHT Ryan, good times -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.
Without touching the html you can insert bullet via css with `:before`.

```
li:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    top: -1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VWnXr/6/

but technically without a workaround its [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142314/css-rendering-inconsistency-on-ul-with-firefox-being-the-odd-ball-out)

Comment: True, but my fault I forgot to include the stipulation that bullets need to be created organically/without use of psuedo elements. Sorry I'll get that added in, but thank you anyways :)

Comment: am assuming that you can't also use graphical bullet either right?

Comment: well then - you should check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142314/css-rendering-inconsistency-on-ul-with-firefox-being-the-odd-ball-out there is no solution without a workaround

Comment: AH AWESOME exactly what i was looking for... if not a solution, then documentation that its not possible (without a workaround). Thanks for digging that up @nol!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55393/discussion-between-pixeloco-and-nol).